# int' does not contain a definition for 'contains' and no extension method 'contains' accepting a first argument of type 'int' could be found

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I am running into below mentioned error using the below LINQ query,what is the equivalent of `not in`SQL to LINQ?I tried as `where !cl.change_list_id.contains(from clcl in bitDB.component_labels_change_lists select clcl.change_list_id)` which isn't working?

```
var lookaheadRunChangeListIds = (from lrcl in bitDB.lookahead_run_change_list
                                 join cl in bitDB.change_lists on lrcl.change_list_id equals cl.change_list_id
                                 where lrcl.lookahead_run_id == lookaheadRunId 
                                 //and cl.change_list_id not in (select clcl.change_list_id from component_labels_change_lists as clcl)
                                 where !cl.change_list_id.contains(from clcl in bitDB.component_labels_change_lists select clcl.change_list_id)                                               
                                 select cl.change_list.ToString()).ToList();
```

Error

> Error  4   'int' does not contain a definition for 'contains' and no extension method 'contains' accepting a first argument of type 'int' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sequence contains the id and not the other way around, this is what the error is stating. You should swap these:

```
!(from clcl in bitDB.component_labels_change_lists 
  select clcl.change_list_id).Contains(cl.change_list_id)
```

You can also try:

```
!bitDB.component_labels_change_lists.Any(clcl => clcl.change_list_id == cl.change_list_id)
```

But Check the generated queries and choose whatever is faster (This might help on this one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1412902/3185569)

Comment: do you have any link or doc I can read to fix these issues by mysefl

Comment: @user3508811 https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/alexj/2009/03/25/tip-8-how-to-write-where-in-style-queries-using-linq-to-entities/

Comment: how can I check the generated queries and check the time?where can I find it?

Comment: @user3508811 check the updated answer, you can write the queries to the Visual Studio console. You can examine the time using the `Stopwatch` class, Google that one to find dozens of examples.

Comment: I tried as `bitDB.log`,it throws an error `Error 1 'Dashboard.EntityFramework.BitDatabaseEntities' does not contain a definition for 'Log' and no extension method 'Log' accepting a first argument of type 'Dashboard.EntityFramework.BitDatabaseEntities' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?`

Comment: why is there a -1 to this answer,is there something wrong with this?please clarify

Comment: @user3508811 Well you said Linq-To-Sql in you question and not entity framework, that's why this is not working. Check the edited answer.